# Estou tentando executar um teste Spring porem não consigo executa-lo

Tags: java, spring-boot, testes

Estou acompanhando um curso onde está sendo criada uma Api com Spring, porém na parte dos testes não estou conseguindo prosseguir e recebo o seguinte erro quando tento executar o teste:

ERRO ao executar teste

> 14:12:24.044 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils -- Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.luiz.demoparkapi.UserIT]: UserIT does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.

Classe do teste

```
package com.luiz.demoparkapi;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.Sql;
import org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient;

import com.api.demopark.web.dto.UserCreateDto;
import com.api.demopark.web.dto.UserResponseDto;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Sql(scripts = "resource/users-insert.sql", executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)
@Sql(scripts = "resource/users-delete.sql", executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
public class UserIT {

    @Autowired
    WebTestClient testClient;

    @Test
    public void createUser_OK() {
        UserResponseDto reponseBody = testClient.post().uri("api/v1/users").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .bodyValue(new UserCreateDto("admin123@gmail.com", "12admin")).exchange().expectStatus().isCreated()
                .expectBody(UserResponseDto.class).returnResult().getResponseBody();

        org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat(reponseBody).isNull();
        org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat(reponseBody.getId()).isNull();
        org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat(reponseBody.getUsername()).isEqualTo("admin123@gmail.com");
        org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat(reponseBody.getRole()).isEqualTo("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

Já fiz diversas tentativas, parece que ele não consegue iniciar o servidor com a porta randomica, não sei onde seria configurado essa anotação de @Configuration